# Draw upper half circle for a tag

Tags: css, hyperlink, draw, geometry

I need to draw a half upper circle like this https://codepen.io/xram/pen/thLsk 
but for **a tag**, I just can use css mostly so I can not add div. Does anybody know how to do it with **a** link.

This only work for div

```
  div{
     height:45px;
     width:90px;
     border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
     -webkit-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
     background:green;
  }
```

Comment: `a` is an inline element, if you add   `display:block;` becomes block element and you can set `width` and `height` as a `div`

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to achieved this

```css
a{
  display:block;
     height:45px;
     width:90px;
     border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
     -webkit-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
     background:green;
  
}
```

```html
<a></a>
```

Comment: Hi, thats right, thank you but how to make the text inside be in the middle, text-align:center but it stays on top of the circle

Comment: add a{    text-align: center;
    line-height: 45px;}

Answer (score 2):

U can make  block or inline-block element. Like this:

```
 a{
 display: block;
 (or use inline-block)
 height:45px;
 width:90px;
 border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
 background:green;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try adding display: block to your anchor tag.

```
<style>
a {
   height: 45px;
   width: 90px;
   border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
   -moz-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
   -webkit-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
   background: green;
   display: block;
}
</style>
<body>
 <a></a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

> div is the block element
>
> a  is the inline element

Block elements have the property to have width , height and etc .. , if you going to apply those styles to an inline element, make that elements as display:block and proceed.